# What is the difference between the Cartesian product of two sets with and set of all function from one set to other?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

There are two sets A and B with cardanlity |A| and |B| respectively.
First talking about Cartesian product - the cardnality of set is |A||B| 
And the cardanility of set of all functions from set A to set B is |A| to the power |B|

but both are formed the same way then why the cardanility are different

Comment: Why do you say that both are formed the same way? A function can be interpreted as a "subset" of a Cartesian product.

Comment: Because they are **not** the same set... Try with a simple example: $A = \{ 1,2 \}$ and $B = \{ a,b,c \}$. $A \times B$ has $2 \times 3 =6$ elements while $A^B$ has $2^3=8$ elements.

Comment: The two sets are most certainly not formed the same way. Why do you think they are formed in the same way?

Comment: A function $\ f:A\to B$ is a subset of the cartesian product $\ A\times B$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In set theory, the set of functions from X to Y may be denoted X → Y or Y^X. Let X and Y be finite sets | say, |X| = n and |Y| = m. Without loss of
generality, you could let X = {1,2,..., n} and Y = {1,2,..m}. Verify that |Y^X|=|Y|^|X|
i.e., |Y^X| = m^n
*    As a special case, the power set of a set X may be identified with the set of all functions from X to {0, 1}, denoted 2^X.

Cartesian product of two sets
X = {a, b}
Y = {1, 2, 3}
Now,
X×Y = {(a,1), (a,2), (a,3), (b,1), (b,2), (b,3)}
Y×X = {(1,a), (1,b), (2,a),(2,b), (3,a), (3,b)}

Answer (score 0):

The members of the Cartesian product $X\times Y$ are ordered pairs of the form $(x,y)$ where $x\in X,y\in Y$, but of course in the family $Y^X$ of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ each member is a function from $X$ to $Y$ not an ordered pair $(x,y)$ as above.